# Correlation between Lumbar Lordosis and shoulder girdle

Tags: anatomy, spine

Is it true that an increase in lumbar lordosis causes more posterior displacement of the shoulders (arms) and greater retraction of the scapulae?

And vice versa: Is it true that retraction of the scapula leads to increased lumbar lordosis?

Are there scientific articles on this subject?

I found information in some sources, but in my opinion, not convincing enough:

1. Advances in Neurology - Volume 64 - Page 73:

> When patients stand for a prolonged period of time, they have a
> tendency to throw the shoulders back and tilt the pelvis down, again
> accentuating the lumbar lordosis.

2. How women bend over backwards for baby

Heidi Ledford (2007):

> The spine took on a curved shape in the lower back, to shift the
> shoulders backwards and move the center of mass above the hips.

https://www.nature.com/articles/news.2007.374